# your.package.namespace - what should it be changed to?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a new project in eclipse for an android app, and I'm going to enter some stuff in a dialog, and I just wonder what the your.package.namespace is and what I am going to write here? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "your.package" section is reserved for a unique id for your apps; I use com.laurencedawson as I own laurencedawson.com. I tend to use the "namespace" to describe the current project, so  if I was releasing an app on SO, it would be com.laurencedawson.so.

More formally here's the [documentation from Google](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html):

> Package Name
>
> This is the package namespace (following the same rules as for packages in the Java programming language) that you want all your
>   source code to reside under. This also sets the package name under
>   which the stub Activity is generated.
>   Your package name must be unique across all packages installed on the Android system; for this reason, it's important to use a standard
>   domain-style package for your applications. The example above uses the
>   "com.example" namespace, which is a namespace reserved for example
>   documentation — when you develop your own applications, you should use
>   a namespace that's appropriate to your organization or entity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, is this something that is easy to change later if a new project is created? I just want to start learning and I can't come up with some fancy name right now that I'm going to use for ever!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ It's a pita to change later (actually, depends on refactor support). The key is that it's unique. In your case, I would use `kreativ.project` (where `project` represents the "sub namespace" of the project as appropriate) or similar. This will ensure it will not conflict with any "proper namespace". For school, for instance, I used `pst.cs420.turtle`. Of course, this should not be done for a released/commercial product, where a domain name really is "the way" ;-)

Comment: @3D-kreativ Usually you use one of your own domains which is guaranteed to be unique. But for personal projects I usually don't bother specifying more than what's necessary (ie only the useful name, say "model") - if backwards compatibility is unimportant (which it is if you don't share your project) every IDE will allow package refactoring without any problems, so you can fix this easily enough for your small first projects later on.

Comment: Can't I use different names for different project?

Comment: It is possible to change later through refactoring the package names and updating the androidmanifest.xml file. However, once you release your app to the market you will not be able to change the package name.

Comment: OK, so next time I create an new app, I'must use the same name?

Answer (score 1):

> To make types easier to find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and
>   to control access, programmers bundle groups of related types into
>   packages.

It's a unique identifier for your application code. Please see the [package naming tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The unique package name your app will use. This is like application id in the market, so if you intend to upload your app to market in the future - make sure it contains app name. I.e. don't just use com.johnsmith but rather go with com.johnsmith.myfancyapp1